# Count unique values within groups and then pivot two into categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataset

```
    Package Document    bool
0   Pkg1    DocumentA   True
1   Pkg1    DocumentA   True
2   Pkg1    DocumentB   True
3   Pkg1    DocumentC   True
4   Pkg2    DocumentA   False
5   Pkg2    DocumentB   True
6   Pkg2    DocumentB   True
7   Pkg2    DocumentC   True
8   Pkg3    DocumentA   False
9   Pkg3    DocumentB   True
10  Pkg3    DocumentD   False
11  Pkg3    DocumentD   True
12  Pkg4    DocumentB   True
13  Pkg4    DocumentC   True
14  Pkg5    DocumentB   False
15  Pkg5    DocumentC   False
```

I need to count the number of packages a document was identified. and then count their respective True False, based on the condition that if even there is one false in that package category it will only be False.
such that
DocumentA is in 3 packages, out of which it has been True once and False Twice. Hope this helps

```
Document Count True False
DocumentA 3 1 2
DocumentB 5 4 1
DocumentC 4 3 1
DocumentD 1 0 1
```

I was able to do the group based count but unable to get to those True False columns by using

```
df.groupby("Document")["Package"].nunique()
```

which gives me

```
Document
DocumentA    3
DocumentB    5
DocumentC    4
DocumentD    1
```

But I also need those additional columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) and then pivot by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), last add count column by [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
print (df.dtypes)
Package     object
Document    object
bool          bool
dtype: object

df["bool"] = df.groupby(["Document",'Package'])["bool"].transform('all')
print (df)
   Package   Document   bool
0     Pkg1  DocumentA   True
1     Pkg1  DocumentA   True
2     Pkg1  DocumentB   True
3     Pkg1  DocumentC   True
4     Pkg2  DocumentA  False
5     Pkg2  DocumentB   True
6     Pkg2  DocumentB   True
7     Pkg2  DocumentC   True
8     Pkg3  DocumentA  False
9     Pkg3  DocumentB   True
10    Pkg3  DocumentD  False
11    Pkg3  DocumentD  False
12    Pkg4  DocumentB   True
13    Pkg4  DocumentC   True
14    Pkg5  DocumentB  False
15    Pkg5  DocumentC  False
```

---

```
df= df.pivot_table(index='Document', 
                   columns='bool', 
                   values='Package', 
                   aggfunc='nunique', 
                   fill_value=0)
df.insert(0, 'count', df.sum(axis=1))
print (df)
bool       count  False  True
Document                     
DocumentA      3      2     1
DocumentB      5      1     4
DocumentC      4      1     3
DocumentD      1      1     0
```

Comment: Document D should yield `1 1 0` not `2 1 1`. `all` needs to be applied when multiple values are found for the same package and document.

Comment: This is not yielding the required result, adding one extra column where document is same i.e. in for DocumentA and DocumentD @Adirio is right

Comment: @jezrael transforming is making every value in the df['bool'] True, making the False column disappear altogether and True column is equal to the count column.

Comment: @Zaibi - Problem with sample data? Added print for check if dtype is `bool` and output after `transfomr`